# rasa_nlu loading data from multiple json files

Tags: python, rasa-nlu

I'm writing a simple Chatbot in Python with rasa_nlu and I would like to load training data from a few separate json files.

Loading one file is a no-problem process with load_data function, but I cannot find a way or feature to help with multiple files (collaboration purposes).

I'm using *rasa_nlu.**version** == 0.14.6*

```py
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data

self.data = "data.json"
training_data = load_data(self.data) # load one json training file
```

I would like self.data to be a list of files instead of one file as string. Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put all the files in a single directory and then specify the directory in `load_data`, e.g. `load_data("my_directory/"`.

Also you could load each file and then merge the training data, e.g.

```
files = ["file1.json", "file2.json"]
training_data = load_data(files[0])

for file in files[1:]:
  data = load_data(file)
  training_data = training_data.merge(data)
```